# Rescale table height and center in beamer frame

Tags: tables, beamer, resize, center

So, I have been trying different options that were suggested in other posts to rescale the height of a way too long table to fit a frame. The `scalebox` option works for me, but afterwards the table is not centered anymore. I tried moving `\centering` but it did not change anything.

```
\documentclass [10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{default}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\begin{document}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]{}%

        \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Sample Characteristics}
        \begin{center}
        \begin{table} [!tbh]
        \caption{Baseline Balance}
        \centering
        \tiny
        \scalebox{0.5}{%
        \begin{tabular}{l c c c}
        \toprule
        & \textbf{Control} & \textbf{Treatment} & \textbf{t-test Difference}\\ 
        & \textbf{(N=754)} & \textbf{(N=771)} & \textbf{(1)-(2)}\\
        \addlinespace[1ex]
        \toprule
        Female  & 0.82  & 0.81  & 0.00\\& (0.01) & (0.01)\\
        \midrule
        Age & 35.59 & 36.37 & -0.78\\
        & (0.46) &  (0.54)\\
        \midrule
        Belongs to scheduled/backward   & 0.47  & 0.45 & 0.02\\
        caste or tribe  & (0.02) &  (0.02)\\
        \midrule
        Married &   0.81 & 0.85 & -0.05**\\
        & (0.01) &  (0.01)\\
        \midrule
        Hindu & 0.76 &  0.78 &  -0.02\\
        & (0.02)     & (0.02)\\
        \midrule
        Household members & 5.01 &  4.97 &  0.04\\
        & (0.08) &  (0.09)\\
        \midrule
        Unemployed &    0.33 & 0.32 & 0.01\\
        & (0.02)     & (0.027)\\
        \midrule
        No education & 0.22 & 0.22 & 0.00\\
        & (0.02)    & (0.02)    \\
        \midrule
        Completed primary education & 0.20  & 0.21  & 0.00\\
        & (0.02)    & (0.01)    \\
        \midrule
        Completed secondary education & 0.36 &  0.39 &  -0.03\\
        & (0.02) &  (0.02)\\
        \midrule
        Completed tertiary education &  0.21 &  0.19 &  0.02\\
        & (0.02)     & (0.01)\\
        \midrule
        Past-month income & 17968.91 & 13262.10 & 4706.80\\
        & (3941.90) & (1754.74)\\
        \midrule
        Past-month savings & 7381.29 & 7933.16 & -551.87\\
        & (1211.84) & (1168.38)\\
        \midrule
        Past-month temptation spending (INR) &  128.06 &    126.14 & 1.92\\
        & (23.11) & (16.84) \\
        \midrule
        Temptation index &  1.47 &  1.44 &  0.03\\
        & (0.03) &  (0.02)\\
        \midrule
        Self-efficacy index & 6.12 &    6.15 &  -0.03\\
        & (0.09)    & (0.09)    \\
        \midrule
        Female empowerment index &  0.02 &  -0.02 & 0.04\\
        & (0.04) &  (0.04)\\
        \midrule
        Outstanding debt & 8810.23  & 10651.75 & -1841.52\\
        & (1994.31) & (2736.34)\\
        \midrule
        Past-month household expenditures  & 5088.60    & 5491.69   & -403.09\\
        (for selected goods) & (398.14) & (435.67)\\
        \midrule
        Resilience index &  0.27 & 0.28 & -0.01\\
        & (0.02) &  (0.02)\\
        \bottomrule
        \addlinespace[01ex]
        F-test of joint significance (F-stat) & & & 0.765\\
        \midrule
        \addlinespace[1ex]
        F-test, number of observations & & & 1525\\
        \bottomrule
        \addlinespace[0.5ex]
        \end{tabular}
        }
        \end{table}
        \end{center}
        \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm quite sure, this table will most likely never fit onto a single beamer frame while still keeping its contents at lease somewhat readable.

Comment: Thank you, and yes, I think so too. I will probably need remove some rows, but will still need to rescale the remaining ones. Do you have an idea on how to approach the centering issue?

Comment: I'd start with carefully evaluating which information is absolutely needed in the presentation. Shorten the table to just include this information. I'd also recommend to not use `\scalebox` on a tabular as this will lead to illegibly small font sizes in many cases, such as yours. Instead, and if your table is still too large, you could split it up onto two frames, present value and error in one line instead of in two and probably also shorten the entries in the first column to save even more space.

Comment: Please also make your code compilable by adding the documentclass and relevant packages to your code (See also: [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)). Also, do you really need `threeparttable` here? You don't seem to use any table notes in this particular table.

Comment: Thanks for the nudge on the MWE and on the `threeparttable`. Indeed, I don't need it and after removing it the table is centered!

Comment: A tiny font at 50% of size? Wrong approach. Simply with all the (n) data in right columns (instead than in bottom rows) and removing the useless  `\midrule`s,  you do not need `\scalebox` at all. Then, think twice is a table with tiny font at 100% is enough readable for a presentation  (a free hint: no).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments?